# Visited status is not contrasted enough in the light theme

Tags: bug

When using the dark theme, I can clearly see if I visited the link:

[image].

But on the light theme I can't:

[image].

Using color picker, I can see the difference: `#2059B1` vs `#2669BE`, but to my eye it's the same color.

Comment: This is a long-standing feature request reported on MSE 11 years ago: [Visited links should be more visible](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/52942/289905). There’s been a redesign which changed the colors, but didn’t improve the contrast (I believe, it made it worse), which spawned more feature requests: [Feedback Requested: Stack Overflow design update of 2014](/a/283654/4642212), [Please swap (or change) the styling colors of visited and non-visited links](/a/396862/4642212) (also as a [separate question](/q/396792/4642212)).